# Searching for an elegant, high school level, technique for solving an integral by hand

Tags: integration

I would appreciate some assistance finding alternative approaches to solving the integral posed in the link below.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rstvj2v3cs

It describes and graphs a progression for decomposing the integral

$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x\sin x}{2+\left|\cos x\right|}dx$

I am hoping for some insight into a simplified approach.

Much appreciated,

**
Thanks to all for the feedback.
I have completed the extended solution in desmos and welcome any additional feedback:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g2lj84ofdu

Comment: At first made an image of your integrand.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: There *is* an image, just click on the link...

Comment: You have added a lot of details about your own attempt in the Desmos link (which is good). You should probably add that here as well, so people don't have to click links to see what your ideas are so far.

Comment: That absolute value in there must go.  Take the part of the integral from $\pi$ to $2\pi$, write $|\cos x|$ as $-\cos(x)$, and change variables to get $0$ to $\pi$.  Add the two integrals.  You get an integral with no $x$ in there.  Easy to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done in a simple way. Split the integral into four parts and substitute
$$x=y,\qquad x={\pi\over2}+y,\qquad x=\pi+y,\qquad x={3\pi\over 2}+y$$ in the four parts. This leads to the integrals
$$\eqalign{&\int_0^{\pi/2}{y\sin y\over2+\cos y}\>dy,\qquad \int_0^{\pi/2}{(\pi/2+y)\cos y\over2+\sin y}\>dy,\cr &\int_0^{\pi/2}{(\pi+y)(-\sin y)\over2+\cos y}\>dy,\qquad\int_0^{\pi/2}{(3\pi/2+y)(-\cos) y\over2+\sin y}\>dy .\cr} $$
The integrals with the same denominator can be collected, whereby the disagreeable parts disappear, and we are left with
$$-\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}{\cos y\over 2+\sin y}\>dy-\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}{\sin y\over 2+\cos y}\>dy=2\pi\log{2\over3}=-2.5476\ .$$

Comment: Thank you for the great insight into the problem. The four integral parts fit nicely with the visual I was hoping to create. I composed a final version of the (perhaps overly verbose) solution in desmos. If you have any additional feedback, it would be appreciated: [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g2lj84ofdu)

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x\sin x}{2+\left|\cos x\right|}dx
\\[1em]
&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\sin x}{2+\left|\cos x\right|}dx 
  + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{x\sin x}{2+\left|\cos x\right|}dx
\end{align}

In the second integral, put $\pi+u=x$. This yields
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\sin x}{2+\left|\cos x\right|}dx + \int_0^{\pi}\frac{(u+\pi)(-\sin u)}{2+\left|\cos u\right|}du
\\[1em]
&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\sin x}{2+\left|\cos x\right|}+\frac{(x+\pi)(-\sin x)}{2+\left|\cos x\right|}dx
\\[1em]
&=-\pi \int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{2+\left|\cos x\right|}
\end{align}

You should be able to solve it from here by putting $\cos x=u$.

I'm getting the final answer as $2\pi \ln \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=−2.54761241$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I selected another answer as it fit more closely with the approach I was taking to generate a graphical split of the functions without the absolute value. If you are interested, I completed the [desmos solution] (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g2lj84ofdu)